# getting unsafe_unretained property error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 id delegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;
```

I got this error; `Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained`

I tried changing the code to the following but i keep getting the same error.

```
__weak id delegate;

@property (nonatomic,weak) id  delegate;
```

When i change it to strong it works, But i don't think that this is the correct way

```
id delegate;

@property (nonatomic,strong) id  delegate;
```

Comment: Yes i did. and i'm trying it for iOS 4.3 and up

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try making the ivar unsafe-unretained as the compiler suggested.

```
{
    __unsafe_unretained id delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

Or just don't declare the ivar, let the system generate it in @synthesize.

Comment: and forgot to mention that this is a ARC enabled project. I'll try your approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
{

}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```